# Cannot load files from local machine in google colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

[Could not fetch resource at : 403 Forbidden
FetchError: Could not fetch resource at : 403 Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWnMR.png)